# While solving a determinant, can't we use an affected row for further operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-decomposition

Book's statement: *"If more than one operation like $R_{i} \rightarrow R_{i}+kR_{j}$
is done in one step, care should be taken to see that a row
that is affected in one operation should not be used in another
operation. A similar remarks applies to column operations."*

My confusion: While solving a determinant of say 3x3, I first calculated the determinant value. Now, I did $R_{1} \rightarrow R_{1}-R_{2}$ and $R_{3} \rightarrow R_{3}-R_{1}$ simultaneously, this new determinant value is still equal to the previously calculated value. Here, I used the mutated Row1 to change Row3, which still gave me the same answer. So, what does the quoted note want to say?

This act of simultaneously using the mutated row to change another row, yet has not given me any wrong answers, I have been using that since 5 days, but since the beginning I have been skeptical regarding this, also, this warning has not been mentioned in my class in which Determinant is about to get over.

Book's Name: "Mathematics ALGEBRA" by Cengage Learning, Page 423; Writer: Ghanshyam Tewari

Comment: Don't do $R_1\to R_1-R_3$ and $R_3\to R_3-R_1$ simultaneously.

Comment: Can we do in different discrete steps?

Comment: But again, if I could do that in discrete steps, does not that indirectly imply the same thing which I did simultaneously? I mean, "we should not do that simultaneously" also means to say that "we should not do that all.", I am not sure though...

Comment: You were lucky, the example you mention could have been done as (i) $R_1\to R_1-R_2$ (ii) with the new rows $R_3\to  R_3-R_1$, then $R_3\to R_3+R_2$. But you would be less lucky if you tried to use simultaneously $R_1\to R_1 + R_2, R_2\to R_2+R_1$ - try it on the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Safe rule: one elementary operation at a time.

Comment: I did one elementary operation at a time, it gave me 1, and i did simultaneous operation it still gave me 1. 1st operation change R1:(1,0) to R1: (1,1), now simultaneously executing the second operation changed R2: (0,1) to (1,2); now calculating determinant gave me 1. I must be doing some mistake, I smell.